# Column in mui-datatable automatically hides on clicking edit icon

Tags: mui-datatable, react-data-table-component

I am using [mui-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables/v/4.2.2) to display users data and I have set firstName column display: false. On changing display to true in viewColumns, it displays the hiddenColumn(firstName) but if I click on edit icon in actions column it hides the default hidden columns that were set to true. I want that if I set any column to display to true by checking the checkbox in viewColumns, it should not hide automatically that column on clicking editIcon.

Here is the columns code for customers datatable:

```
const columns = [
    {
      name: "_id",
      label: "User Id",
      options: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "firstName",
      label: "First Name",
      options: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "lastName",
      label: "Last Name",
      options: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "userImage",
      label: "User Image",
      options: {
        display: false,
        viewColumns: false,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "name",
      label: "Name",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (_, { rowData }) => (
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", textAlign: "start" }}>
            <Avatar src={rowData[3]} sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
              {getInitials(rowData[1])}
            </Avatar>
            <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="subtitle2">
              {rowData[1]} {rowData[2]}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        ),
      },
    },
    {
      name: "phoneNumber",
      label: "Phone",
    },
    {
      name: "userRole",
      label: "User Role",
    },
    {
      name: "isVerified",
      label: "User Verified",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value) => (
          <SeverityPill color={value ? "success" : "error"}>
            {value ? "Verified" : "Not Verified"}
          </SeverityPill>
        ),
      },
    },
    {
      name: "createdAt",
      label: "Registration Date",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value) => format(new Date(value), "dd/MM/yyyy"),
      },
    },
    {
      name: "updatedAt",
      label: "Updated At",
      options: {
        display: false,
        customBodyRender: (value) => format(new Date(value ?? new Date()), "dd/MM/yyyy"),
      },
    },
    {
      name: "view",
      label: "View",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (_, { rowData }) => (
          <NextLink href={`/customers/${rowData[0]}`}>
            <VisibilityIcon color="primary" sx={{ mx: 1, cursor: "pointer" }} />
          </NextLink>
        ),
      },
    },
    {
      name: "actions",
      label: "Actions",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (_, { rowData }) => {
          const actions = [
            {
              Icon: EditIcon,
              iconColor: "warning",
              handleClick: () => handleUpdateClick(rowData[0]),
            },
            {
              Icon: VerifiedUserIcon,
              iconColor: "success",
              handleClick: () => handleVerifyClick(rowData[0]),
            },
            {
              Icon: DeleteIcon,
              iconColor: "error",
              handleClick: () => handleDeleteClick(rowData[0]),
            },
          ];

          return <ActionButton actions={actions} />;
        },
      },
    },
  ];
```

Then I'm using a reusable custom mui-datatable component:

```
<CustomMUIDataTable
        title="All Customers"
        columns={columns}
        data={customers}
        Toolbar={Toolbar}
      />
```

And here is the CustomMUIDataTable component:

```
import React from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

const CustomMUIDataTable = ({ title, columns, data, Toolbar, customOptions }) => {
  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={title}
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      options={{
        customToolbar: () => <Toolbar />,
        selectableRows: "none",
        filterType: "dropdown",
        responsive: "standard",
        download: false,
        print: false,
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 20, 100],
        sortOrder: {
          name: "createdAt",
          direction: "desc",
        },
        ...customOptions,

        setRowProps: () => {
          return {
            style: { borderBottom: "2px solid #eee", textAlign: "center" },
          };
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomMUIDataTable;
```

I tried defining a new state named columnState in the CustomMUIDataTable component and setting columns to that state. Then with the help of onTableChange option, if the action is onViewColumnsChange, set the columnState to tableState.columns but it does not render the customBodyRender columns something like this:

[image]

Here firstName is the column that is firstly hidden.

Here is the code with onTableChange:

```
import React from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

const CustomMUIDataTable = ({ title, columns, data, Toolbar, customOptions }) => {
  const [columnState, setColumnState] = React.useState(columns);

  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={title}
      columns={columnState}
      data={data}
      options={{
        customToolbar: () => <Toolbar />,
        selectableRows: "none",
        filterType: "dropdown",
        responsive: "standard",
        download: false,
        print: false,
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 20, 100],
        sortOrder: {
          name: "createdAt",
          direction: "desc",
        },
        ...customOptions,

        setRowProps: () => {
          return {
            style: { borderBottom: "2px solid #eee", textAlign: "center" },
          };
        },
        onTableChange: (action, tableState) => {
          console.log("action", action, tableState);
          if (action === "viewColumnsChange") {
            setColumnState(tableState.columns);
          }
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomMUIDataTable;
```

Firstly customers list is like this:

[image]